# Angular component . Set variable in the constructor

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set a variable in the constructor and use it to specify the path to the c# controller. The name of the variable is baseUrl.

```
angular.module('adminService', []).factory('adminService', function ($rootScope, $http, $location) {

var adminService = function () {
    this.baseUrl = $location.protocol() + "://" + location.host + "/";
}
adminService.prototype.getTopics = function () {
    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl + '/Admin/getTopics',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    return promise;
}
return new adminService;
```

});

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The baseUrl variable is undefined whenever I try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have formated your code a bit and used best practices. This should work:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

angular.module('adminService', [])     // be CAREFUL bcz you are CREATING the module here! 
    .factory('adminService', adminService);

function adminService($rootScope, $http, $location) {

    return {
        getTopics: getTopics
    };

    this.baseUrl = $location.protocol() + "://" + location.host + "/";
    var vm = this;

    var getTopics = function () {
        var promise = $http(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: vm.baseUrl + '/Admin/getTopics',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
        return promise;
    };
};
})();
```

Mind that $rootScope is not used